# CORS error when trying to sqs.sendMessage to my SQS via API Gateway

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

At the final stages of implementing my POST request into my web app and began receiving cors errors. These happen all the time so I spent the following hour or so configuring things inside my API Gateway to fix it but with no luck.

I have an Angular application that is making an sqs.sendMessage request to my API method URL.

```
QueueUrl: "https://gzi9gu1m08.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Testing/test"

let sendSqsMessage = sqs.sendMessage(sqsOrderData).promise();

sendSqsMessage.then((data) => {
     console.log(`Booking Status | SUCCESS: ${data.MessageId}`);
 }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(`Booking Status | ERROR: ${err}`);
 });
```

Inside my API Gateway, I have a GET and POST method, each under different resources. My GET method is working fine, and I've configured my POST with the correct headers. I've also tried Actions -> Enable CORS and deploying.

[image: headers]

When I test my SQS POST I receive back a status code of 200 and the appropriate headers.

[image: response]

But when I try to POST from my application I receive this error. I'm noticing how the QueueURL is missing my resource and method at the end of the link so maybe that has something to do with it?

[image: cors error]

Really hoping to get this finished today so any help is much appreciated.

Any questions or further information required, please ask.

[Edit]

I think I've configured my OPTIONS correctly, this is my OPTIONS integration response.

[image: OPTIONS]

[SOLVED]

I fixed it! The problem was I was using an API request in my sqs.sendMessage, when I should have been using the SQS Url instead. No need to even have an API Gateway POST request if you approach it with the guide found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html).

Answer (score 1):

The CORS headers don't go on the `POST` endpoint. You shouldn't be configuring CORS headers manually in AWS API Gateway like that. CORS headers are returned from an `OPTIONS` request, not a `POST` request. To get API Gateway to return the CORS headers you want, [follow this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) in the official documentation.

Comment: I've tried it with just OPTIONS and it didn't work either so I decided I would have to start manually configuring it

Comment: The error message you are getting says that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is missing from the preflight (OPTIONS) response.

Comment: Check edit, I've added a new photo

Comment: Do I need to create a mapping template for my OPTIONS response?

Comment: No, you don't need a mapping template. If this is a REST API all you should need to do is click the "Enable CORS" option: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html Try following this official troubleshooting guide https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cors-errors/

Comment: Figured it out. Problem was I didn't even need the API Gateway to make these requests, just the SQS Url istelf. Thanks for the help though, got me thinking about all the parts and I finally copped it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the remote server has you allowed/whitelisted on the CORS policy, you won't be able to make AJAX based requests unless you either:

1. Use a reverse CORS proxy, great example is https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere very easy to implement. There's many others such as https://allorigins.win/ simply appending the URL after the proxy would render CORS useless;
2. Make a jump page, CURL the page not using AJAX and make your page's AJAX call to your jump page; because you can send a GET AJAX request to your own page, and utilize CURL to mimic a browser visit (set user agent, etc); your return the CURL response to your AJAX reciever;

I've always solved these via method 1 which is using a CORS proxy; it's the best way IMO

Comment: Awesome, I'll have a go at trying to implement this and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Creating a proxy server here is entirely unneeded, and some of the methods suggested in this answer would present serious security concerns. AWS API Gateway supports CORS already (see my answer).

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted.. but alright; I tried to help. I faced this issue many times and often by using a CORS proxy I've overcome it; sharing my solution didn't deserve a downvote I didn't mislead - but whatever, it is what it is - cheers.

Comment: I've tried implementing the proxy and it's giving me issues relating to missing modules 'https'. Followed a guide on setting ``"browser:{"https":false}`` in my package.json and it compiles but no longer loads anything on the page

Comment: I just now realized your using AWS lol, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html you an set a cors policy to allow your app; again proxy is only useful when going outside of your environment :)

Comment: Ahahaha apologies, probably should have mentioned that. Give him his upvote back @MarkB ;)

Comment: heh it's all good man, hope you beat your issue :)